# change pointer according to condition in C (asterisk 1.4 cdr struct)

Tags: c, pointers

How can I perform following? full_agentstring needs to be pointed either to cdr->channel or cdr->dstchannel:

```
....
char *cdr_channel = cdr->channel;
char *cdr_dstchannel = cdr->dstchannel;
char *full_agentstring = NULL;
if(strstr(cdr_channel, agent_pattern) != NULL) {
      *full_agentstring = cdr->channel;
} else if(strstr(cdr_dstchannel, agent_pattern) != NULL) {
      *full_agentstring = cdr->dstchannel;
```

I tried as well `full_agentstring = &cdr_dstchannel` but still getting warning:

assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Comment: What is the type of `cdr->channel` or `cdr->dstchannel`? Is it a pointer or `char`?

Comment: @AntoJurković  Please take look, I have updated the topic

Comment: Both are the same type, so you don't need to dereference, `full_agentstring = cdr->channel;` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(strstr(cdr_channel, agent_pattern) != NULL) {
      full_agentstring = cdr->channel;
} else if(strstr(cdr_dstchannel, agent_pattern) != NULL) {
      full_agentstring = cdr->dstchannel;
```

Or if I have understood your question incorrectly then here is second approach

```
char *cdr_channel = cdr->channel;
char *cdr_dstchannel = cdr->dstchannel;
char **full_agentstring = NULL;
if(strstr(cdr_channel, agent_pattern) != NULL) {
      full_agentstring = &cdr->channel;
} else if(strstr(cdr_dstchannel, agent_pattern) != NULL) {
      full_agentstring = &cdr->dstchannel;
```